# Discrepancy in Azure SQL DTU reporting?

Tags: azure-sql-database

Refer to DTU graph below.

•   Both graphs show DTU consumption for the same period, but captured at different times.
•   Graph on the left was captured minutes after DTU-consuming event;
•   Graph on the right was captured some 19 hrs after.

Why are the two graphs different?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the scale of the data points: your graph shows the same scale on the bottom (likely through use of the 'custom' view of the DTU percentage and other metrics) but the granularity of the data has changed. [This is a similar question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/588fb6ff-d688-49a7-add7-75e141a183f7/the-dtus-is-different-in-different-time-range?forum=ssdsgetstarted) - the granularity for the last hour of data is 5 seconds, whereas the scale for multiple hours is 5 minutes - and the average of the 100 datapoints is the value for that 5 minute data point.

I'll verify this with the engineering team and update if it is inaccurate.

Comment: There are two important insights I need from the graph.  First is trend:   How much of total capacity (DTU-wise) on average am I running at?   The existing graphs give this info.   Second is peak usage: how far am I from my maximum capacity *at any point in time*?   The latter is important because whenever I hit peak, the application gets throttled down and appears to hang.   When you avg out the data points for any period older than an hour, these peaks get smoothed out.  What is the best way to report historical peak DTU usage?